# Swift: Segue(modal) to a UITableViewController which embeded in antoher navigation controller

Tags: ios, casting, segue

**Background**: I want to display a modal segue from a UITableViewController(A) to a UITableViewController(B), but I want to show a NavigationBar to "Cancel" and "Save".

---

**What I've done**: 
In storyboard:

1. I ctrl drag the cell from A to B, and set segue identifer "selectItem"
2. I choose B and select "Editor - Embed in - Navigation Controller"

In A's ViewController:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifer == "selectItem" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as B
            // Pass value from A to B
        }
    }
}
```

[image: storyboard]

---

**Error**:The app crashed at `let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as B` with the error `swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional`. If I didn't embed a navigation controller to B, the program would not crash. But I really need a navigation bar. 
Is there any solution or other way to achieve this? Thank you!
[image: error 1]
[image]

---

PS: I tried drag a NavigationBar from object library in storyboard, but it's miss a part of background to cover statusbar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!
I added a BreakPoint at the line `let dest = segue.destinationViewController as B`, and I found that `segue.destinationViewController` is `NavigationController` type. So I fixed it by replacing this line to:

```
let dest = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
let bVC = dest.topViewController as B
```

and do some passing value stuff.
Hope this will help other people facing this problem.

Answer (score 5):

1. Create both of the `UITableViewController` in your storyboard.
2. Select your Second `UITableViewController` (the one you want to present modally), and embed it in an `UINavigationController`.
3. Add the "**Cancel**" and "**Save**" `UIBarButtonItem` into `UINavitionItem` of the Second `UITableViewController`.
4. Select the `UITablViewCell` of your First `UITableViewController`
5. `Control+Drag` into your `UINavigationController`.
6. Select "`Present Modally`" under the "Selecteion Segue" option from the dropdown list.
7. To pass data in your First `UITableViewController` override the method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "identifier" {
            let destination = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
            let bViewController = destination.topViewController as BViewController

            // pass data
        }
}
```

Here are the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

This should do the job, Cheers!

Comment: I can do a segue to show the 2nd tableViewController, but thing is I can't pass a value using preparedForSegue method(when I casting destinationViewController to 2nd tableVC). I just solved it! Thank you anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
if let b = segue.destinationViewController.childViewControllers.first as? B {
    //do something with b
}
```

for this scenario. It is really just a syntax difference though.